# Dockerize react/next js based on multiple environment - alpha, beta, production

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, next.js

I have multiple environments that i need to dockerize my react/nextjs code. For local i use the .env file for my environment variables. I git-ignore the .env so its not pushed to the repo. When i want to deploy to alpha i want the env variable to change (say for alpha the env API_ENDPOINT=api-aplha.xyz.com and for beta it is api-beta.xyz.com and for production it is api.xyz.com). I want to have single dockerfile and don't want multiple env file such env.prod or env.beta. What is the best approach to handle such situations and how to approach this problem.

Comment: You already have the approach - extract to environment variables. Use dotenv locally, then in your other environments _provide actual env vars_. That way your container is identical, it's only the configuration that varies.

Comment: Providing env to other environments how should I do it use a bash script and have conditional in it to load env or how?? I have a overall grasp of idea my confusion is on actual implementation